# Signalr Personal Chat

Tags: signalr

I am still new to `signalr`. I want to make chat application with `signalR` and having a problem with the personal chat and groups because the connection id always changes every time the user and reconnect.

**Question :** How we know which id user is reference the specific user. if the connection id always change.
(because if the user open another tab in their browser the signalR will recognize them as another user. How do we know that the id is the same person)

Is there any unique property from `signalR` that we can save in database so when the user login when can  recognize the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UserNames` of the logged in users. Depending on the technology you use, you can utilize different methods. The way I do it in MVC is like the following:
Hub:

```
 public class ChatHub :Hub
    {
        public void SendMessage(string sender,string receiver, string msg)
        {
            MessageService messageService = new MessageService();
            long msgId = messageService.Add(sender, receiver, msg);
            Clients.User(receiver).receiveMessage(sender, msg, msgId);
            Clients.User(sender).receiveMessage(sender, msg, msgId);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
   $('#send').click(function () {
        hub.invoke("SendMessage", "@User.Identity.Name", "@ViewBag.Receiver", $('#message').val());
    });
```

The sender UserName can be obtained by @User.Identity.Name (in MVC) and the receiver UserName can be read when the sender is opening the receiver chat.

**Update**:
Regarding Asp.Net Web Forms, check if the following helps:
[SignalR-with-ASP-NET-One-to-one-and-Group-Chat](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1100425/SignalR-with-ASP-NET-One-to-one-and-Group-Chat-wit)

Comment: you mean IUserID provider ? because i don't understand how to use that

Comment: if i don't using mvc. Is there is any alternative, sir ? i user normal webform(.aspxfile)(Sorry, i don't know the name of technology i am user either)

Comment: Thank you sir for apply my question. Since now, i start to realize that. i want to use the Clients.User("userName").someMethodinClient. But i don't know how to set the userName value in the client side(may be in js script(i don't know precisely)) so when the server Clients.User("userName").someMethodinClient from client, the server will know which client must be invoke.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is doing what it should do with each connect/reconnect. Your user is establishing a new connection, so they get a new connection ID.

If they open in a new tab that will create a new connection. You have to work out users being currently connected and how you want to handle.

If you take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) you can see they have examples for mapping users to connections.

Comment: i don't undersand where i should put the code(public interface IUserIdProvider). and how we set the id from the client